# How do I shift text over in an inline-block in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move the Status/Actions Text over to the left but no matter how much I mess with the CSS nothing works! 
[What it is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2aqg.png)

[What I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXWmy.png)

[HTML code for that section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXL4g.png)

[CSS for that section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGfNA.png)

```css
.top {
  background: #1b1b1e;
  width: 1650px;
  margin: auto;
}

li a {
  display: inline—block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="linkText">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="statusText">Status</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="actionText">Action</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code - post the code itself.

Comment: I have added code. Please check. If any changes please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please apply this :

```css
.top {
  background: #1b1b1e;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.link-wrap {
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.top ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.top ul li {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.top ul li a,
.link-wrap a {
  display: inline—block;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.link-wrap a {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="link-wrap">
    <a href="#" id="linkText">Link</a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="statusText">Status</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="actionText">Action</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If any changes please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.top {
                background: #1b1b1e;
                width: 100%;
                margin: auto;
                float: left;
                padding: 10px 0;
            }

            .top ul {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }

            .top li {
                list-style-type: none;
                float: left;
                width: 230px;
            }

            li a {
                display: inline—block;
                padding: 1em;
                color: #9c9c9c;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-align: left;
                font-size: 25px;
                letter-spacing: 1.1px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .statusText {
                float: right !important;
            }

            .actionText {
                float: right !important;
                max-width: 149px;

            }
```

```html
 <div class="top">
            <ul>
                <li class="linkText"><a href="#" id="linkText">Link</a></li>
                <li class="actionText"><a href="#" id="actionText">Action</a></li>
                <li class="statusText"><a href="#" id="statusText">Status</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexbox order property:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you are good to go with flex, a few lines of code will fix your issue.

**display: flex;**

```css
.top {
  background: #1b1b1e;
  /* width: 1650px; */
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

.statusText {
    margin-left: auto;
}

li a {
  display: inline—block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* margin-right: 10em; */
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="linkText">Link</a></li>
        <li class="statusText"><a href="#" id="statusText">Status</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="actionText">Action</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you are interested to go with display inline-block only, you can use the float property.

**display: inline-block;**

```css
.top {
  background: #1b1b1e;
  /* width: 1650px; */
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;;
    list-style: none;
}

li a {
  display: inline—block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* margin-right: 10em; */
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="linkText">Link</a></li>

        <!-- Reversed Order -->
        <li class="float-right"><a href="#" id="actionText">Action</a></li>
        <li class="float-right"><a href="#" id="statusText">Status</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.top {
  background: #1b1b1e;
  width: 1650px;
  margin: auto;
}
ul{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse; 
   }

li a {
  display: inline—block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="linkText">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="statusText">Status</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="actionText">Action</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .top {
        background: #1b1b1e;
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    li a {
        display: inline—block;
        /* padding: 1em; */
        color: #9c9c9c;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 25px;
        letter-spacing: 1.1px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-right: 1em;
    }

     ul li:not(:first-child) {
        float: right;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="top">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="linkText">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="statusText">Status</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="actionText">Action</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Another way to achieve what you want, But I would suggest just like others to use flex box :)